# Проверка в сети ли пользователь php

Tags: php

Всем привет, на днях решил написать скрипт, определяющий, находится ли человек на сайте на PHP.
написал, вроде все работает, но столкнулся с проблемой, что когда кто-то из пользователей в сети, отображается, что все пользователи в сети, но только если человек авторизован.
Если же нет, все правильно, выдает когда человек был в сети.
Вот код:

```
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_base);
$id = $_COOKIE['id'];
$current = time();
$quer="UPDATE users SET online='$current' WHERE id='$id'";
$resul = mysqli_query($mysqli, $quer);
$time = ($current - $row[9])/60;
                if($resul) {
    echo '<p class="online">online</p>';
}
else {
    echo ' <p class="onliner">минут назад</p>';

    ?>&nbsp;<?
    echo '<p class="ch">'.(int)$time.'</p>';
     echo '<p class="online">Был в сети:</p>';
}
```

[image: профиль другого пользователя, когда я вошел]

Comment: Не ясно откуда берется $row . Где то должна быть проверка сколько времени прошло с последнего посещения, однако ее не видно.

Comment: $row - присутствует в коде выше. $row[9] - значение в базе данных под 9 номером столбца.

Answer (score 0):

Ты пропустил

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($resul);
```